# Multiple y values for single x value, how to find maximum y value

Tags: matlab

Simple question which has me stumped.

I have a 2D matrix of values;

```
 x     y
 1     1.568
 2     2.457
 2     7.778
 3     5.124
 1     7.985
 2     6.025
 3     3.505
```

There is a repeating x value, [1 2 3] and corresponding y values.

I would like to extract just the maximum y value from each unique x value.

I've tried various things but no luck. The closest I got was using;

```
x_y = [unique(x_y(:,1)),accumarray(x_y(:,1),x_y(:,2),[],@max)]
```

But I had this error; "Error using horzcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent."

Answer (score 4):

You're close. You can take advantage of the fact that the values contained in `x` are the subscripts you want to use in `accumarray`, then its a matter of specifying the correct output size. In this case, the number of unique values in `x`.

Let's define `x`, `y` and `x_y`:

```
x = [1;2;2;3;1;2;3]
y = [1.568;2.457;7.778;5.124;7.985;6.025;3.505]

x_y = [x y]


m = accumarray(x_y(:,1),x_y(:,2),[numel(unique(x_y(:,1))) 1],@max)
m =

    7.9850
    7.7780
    5.1240
```

yay!

Comment: Hi. That was quick! I was perhaps trying to be too general in my question. What would you do if your x values are (1) not integers (but can be rounded without too much loss of accuracy), and (2) are not always spaced by equal values? Such that you can't take advantage of the stepping of indices.

Comment: @bobby-brains In that case do `[~, ~, x2] = unique(x);` to reduce the `x` values to integers, and then use `x2` instead of `x`, i.e. define `x_y = [x2 y];` and then call `accumarray`

Answer (score 2):

[Benoit's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32010492/5211833) is still the way to go. I assume you still have exactly the same values for `x`, in that case simply do:

```
x_unique = unique(x);
x_ind = 1:length(x_unique);
```

`x_unique` selects all exactly equal values of your `x` array. If they are not exactly equal (1.0001 ~=1.0000 eg) this will not work and you will have to round your array anyway. So, if you have and array `x`:

```
x = [1,2,3,3,4,5,5,6,7]
unique(x) = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

The command `unique` does exactly what its name suggests it does: return all unique entries into the array. If you array now is a non-integer array, `unique` will return those non-integer values. If Im not mistaken `accumarray` creates a grid based on the first argument, thus they have to be integers. To make sure all your unique values of `x` get the same integer value assigned to them, you can create an array `x_ind = 1:length(x_unique)`, which gives you an array of exactly as many integers as you have unique values in your original `x`. This basically means each unique value of `x` is assigned an integer value which can be processed by `accumarray`.
Afterwards your maximum values will be located in a matrix which looks as in Benoit's example, where the sorting is on increased integer. That integer however, is just a placeholder for your actual x-value, the one you want, at `x_unique(x_ind)`.

This gives you an integer array of indices, which can later be tracked back to the original value of x using `x_unique(x_ind)`.
Switch your array to using the `x_ind` instead of the originals, then you can pick up Benoit's code at

```
x_y = [x y];
```

Comment: Thank you for the input A. You'll have to forgive me a little as I'm not entirely following. I don't quite see that the output of x_ind means.